# Forcing an Android tablet to connect to a WiFi from PC

Tags: wi-fi, adb, broken-screen

A while ago, I had a tablet (Coby Kyros MID9742), that got shelved when the screen quit (half of the area of the touchscreen won't recognize touches, split among 2 sections).

I am trying to repurpose the tablet for use as a video player via HDMI cable to projector, with my old phone (Galaxy S, no problems) as a remote. I have that part worked out, using a 3rd party app.

But the main problem is getting the tablet to connect to WiFi to use the remote software. The screen is broken in such a way that the center strip (top to bottom in portrait mode) cannot recognize touches, and I cannot put in the WiFi password that I need to. The tablet does not know the password for the WiFi.

**Is there some way that I can force the tablet to connect to an encrypted WiFi using my PC, via USB cable?** The tablet is rooted, but I have not flashed a custom ROM onto it.

**Also, is there some way that I can force WiFi to turn on at startup, and automatically connect to specified network?**

If there is any more information I need to add, please say so in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to connect your tablet with a router without entering the password. Nowadays, in almost all WiFi routers, there is an option called WPS (Wi-Fi Protected Setup). It can be seen in the routers, usually with a lock sign.

So, you can select the router from the list populated, and while prompting for the password, you can press the WPS key in the router. This will enable you to automatically set up the Wi-Fi without even entering the passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write anything about the Android version running on your device. Assuming it is capable of acting as OTG host (if unsure, you can find out using some [OTG Checker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_storagemedia#group_534)), you could try attaching some USB keyboard (and mouse) to it in order to control input. This would allow you to not only activate WiFi and chose the network, but also to enter the credentials when needed.